# Add the values in a Jtable together

Tags: java, jtable

How do I get the sum of a particular column in a Jtable as the user inserts values into the Table?

Comment: Is `TableModel` used? For example, a `DefaultTableModel` has handy methods which return values of cells.

Comment: DefaultTableModel is used. But i don't seem to know to actual method or looping statement to add all the values in a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your `TableModel`. Whenever a value is changes you store the value in the model and then you loop through all the rows in the model to recalculate the total. You use the `getValueAt(...)` method to get the values as you do the looping.

Or, if the total value is not displayed in the table, but in some other Swing component, you would probably want to use a `TableModelListener`. An event is generated whenever the data changes so again you would just loop through all the rows in the `TableModel using the`getValueAt(...)` method.

The implementation of the TableModelListener might be something like:

```
TableModelListener tml = new TableModelListener()
{

    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE)
        {
            int column = e.getColumn();

            if (column == ???)
            {
                TableModel model = (TableModel)e.getSource();
                double total = 0;

                for (int row = 0; row < model.getRowCount(); row++)
                {
                    double value = ((Double)model.getValueAt(row, ???2)).doubleValue();
                    total += value;
                }

                System.out.println( total );
            }
        }
    }
});

JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(tml);
```

Comment: k. Thanks a lot. You helped a great deal